# Apache Beam Java SDK Extensions : Sorter

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Please find below the snippet of 'sorter' module I'm trying to implement :

```
// Group by primary key, bringing <SecondaryKey, Value> pairs for the same key together.
   PCollection<KV<Integer, Iterable<KV<String, Integer>>>> grouped =
           joinedPcollection.apply(GroupByKey.<Integer, KV<String, Integer>>create());


//    For every primary key, sort the iterable of <SecondaryKey, Value> pairs by secondary key.
  PCollection<KV<Integer, Iterable<KV<String, Integer>>>> groupedAndSorted =
       grouped.apply(
           SortValues.<Integer, String, Integer>create(BufferedExternalSorter.options()));
```

I have resolved all the dependencies but still getting `'NoClassDefFoundError'`. Below is the stack trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sorter.BufferedExternalSorter.create(BufferedExternalSorter.java:98)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sorter.SortValues$SortValuesDoFn.processElement(SortValues.java:153)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sorter.SortValues$SortValuesDoFn$auxiliary$gkDhO7uE.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.repackaged.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:197)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.repackaged.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:158)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.repackaged.runners.core.SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.processElementInReadyWindows(SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator.processElement(ParDoEvaluator.java:181)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.processElement(DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.java:51)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.processElements(TransformExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me tackling this issue.

Comment: can you share your dependencies list. hadoop libraries might be missing.

Comment: Do we need hadoop libraries? My source datafile is placed in GCS and I have to pull the data from there and perform 'sorting' operations over them. How come 'Hadoop' be in the picture?

Comment: Thank you @ jkff. It worked